# ARM template: Way to workaround for nested copy in variable section

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using azure-arm template and below attempt in creating copy iteration failed in variables section. This is giving me error, saying nested is not supported, Am I missing anything, if nested copy is not supported, how to go ahead in creating array of objects containing array.

```
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "VmInfo",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]",
        "input": {
          "skuQualVmName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-vm-', copyIndex('VmInfo',1))]",
          "copy": [
            "name": "vmInterfaceNames",
            "count": "[parameters('nicCountPerVm')]",
            "input": "[concat(parameters(vmName), '-vm-', copyIndex('VmInfo',1), '-nic-', copyIndex('vmInterfaceNames',1))]"
        ]
        }
      }
    ],
```

Also I want to know if mutliple copy statements are supported in variables, like below

```
....
"copy": [
            {
                "name": "publicIpAdressResourceArray",
                "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]",
                "input": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',concat('primary-ip-', parameters('vmNames')[copyIndex('publicIpAdressResourceArray')]))]"
               }
            }
        ]
    },
   "copy": [
      {
        "name": "networkInterfaceNames",
        "count": "[mul(parameters('vmCount'),parameters('nicCountPerVm'))]",
        "input": "[concat(  parameters('vmNameSubString'), '-vm-', div(copyIndex('networkInterfaceNames'),parameters('nicCountPerVm')), '-nic-', mod(copyIndex('networkInterfaceNames'),parameters('nicCountPerVm')))]"
      }
    ],
....
```

Answer (score 1):

first copy is correct, for the second question, you can do this:

```
"copy": [
    {
        "name": "firstvar",
        xxx
    },
    {
        "name": "secondvar",
        yyy
    }
]
```

so just use a single copy statement for all the var iterations you need. if you are looking for a property of a variable, to be an array that needs to be generated\calculated - you can use nested deployments:

1. create base variable
2. pass it into a nested deployment
3. pass all the relevant data to calculate your second array
4. create a new variable in the nested deployment with the desired structure
5. output it and use it

but, probably, your best bet - is calculating this outside of an arm template.

Comment: Regarding the firstone  I am getting below error:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 11:21:44 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template 'copy' definition at line '197' and column '17' has nested copy arrays. The
use of nested copy arrays is not supported. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.'.

Comment: ah, didnt notice tyou have copy inside the first one, its not possible, like i said